Function App time trigger not working as expected
I have this Time Trigger Function that runs PowerShell code to fetch Azure storage accounts used capacity metrics based on the tags. The code works fine when I trigger the job manually and gives me the accurate details but fetches 0 value from all the storage accounts in its schedule run.
The PowerShell used SPN authentication for all the storage accounts.
param($Timer)

# Get environment variables
$tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
$thumb = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_THUMBID')
$appId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPID')
$appName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPNAME')

Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to call UC API"

# Connect to Azure with SPN
try {
    Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumb -ApplicationId $appId
    $subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
    Write-Host "Subscriptions fetched: $($subscriptions.Count)"
} catch {
    Write-Warning "Failed to connect to Azure with SPN login. Skipping."
    return
}

# Define the tag key
$tagKey = "Business Data Domain"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$strg = @()
$current_date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    try {
        Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
        Write-Host "Set context to subscription: $($subscription.Name)"
        
        $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) }
        Write-Host "Storage accounts found in subscription $($subscription.Name): $($storageAccounts.Count)"
        
        if ($storageAccounts.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Host "No storage accounts with tag '$tagKey' found in subscription $($subscription.Name)."
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to set context for subscription: $($subscription.Name). Skipping."
        continue
    }
    
    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        Write-Host "Processing storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"

        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"
        
        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            Write-Host "Metrics response for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $($response.Content)"
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }
            
            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
                Write-Host "Average Capacity for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $averageCapacity"
            } else {
                Write-Host "Metric 'UsedCapacity' not found for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)."
                $averageCapacity = 0
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Error retrieving metrics for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $($_.Exception.Message)"
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }

                
        # Create a custom object for each storage account
        $objresults = [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName    = $subscription.Name
            StorageAccount      = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
            UsedCapacityInBytes = $averageCapacity
            TagName             = $tagKey
            TagValue            = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
        }
        # Add the object to the results array
        $strg += $objresults
    }

}

<#Write-Host "Completed fetching storage account details for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to process storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName). Skipping."
        }#>
    


Write-Host "Checking if strg has data before exporting to CSV..."
if ($strg.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No data found in strg array!"
} else {
    Write-Host "strg array contains data. Proceeding to export..."
}

# Create folder to store source path
$localPath = "$(Get-Location)\strgacctmp"
If (-not (Test-Path -Path $localPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $localPath -ItemType 'Directory' -Force
    Write-Host "New Folder strgacctmp Created!"
} else {
    Write-Host "Folder already Exists!"
}

<# Create folder to store source path 
$localPath = "$(Get-Location)\unitycatalogtmp"
If (Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
    Write-Host "Folder already Exists!"
}
else {
    New-Item -Path "$localPath" -ItemType 'Directory' -Name unitycatalogtmp -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    Write-Host "New Folder unitycatalogtemp Created!"
}#>


function uploadFileToBlob {
    param(
        [String] $LocalFilePath,
        [String] $TargetFileName
    )
    $tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
    $storage_account = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT')
    $subscription = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME')
    $filesystemName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME')
    $destPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_FOLDER_PATH_UC_DASHBOARD')

    Write-Host " ----Retrieved App Settings from Function App--- "
    Write-Host "ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT - $storage_account"
    Write-Host "ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME - $subscription"
    Write-Host "ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME - $filesystemName"
    Write-Host "Source - $LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "Destination Path - $destPath"
    Write-Host "Path from where files will be uploaded: $LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "-------------------------"

    $tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
    $thumb = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_THUMBID')
    $appId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPID')
    $appName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPNAME')

    Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to upload to ADLS"

    
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_account -UseConnectedAccount -ErrorAction Stop
    #$ctx

    try {
        $destPath += "/" + $TargetFileName
        New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $destPath -Source $LocalFilePath -ErrorAction Stop -Force
        Start-Sleep -seconds 2

        # Will execute on successful completion of folder upload
        Write-Host "File uploaded successfully!"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output " Error occured as below"
        $_
        exit
    }
}

# Export to CSV        
$CsvPath = $localPath + "\edpstrgaccsize$current_date.csv"
$strg | Export-Csv -Path $CsvPath -NoTypeInformation

#Upload to blob
$targetFileName = "edpstrgaccsize$($current_date).csv"
uploadFileToBlob -LocalFilePath $CsvPath -TargetFileName $targetFileName

Write-Host "Uploaded Storage Details-"

#Need to delete locally stored files in folder unitycatalogtmp
Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Filter *.csv | Remove-Item -Recurse

Write-Host "Script Completed"



Function.json
{
 "bindings": [
 {
   "name": "Timer",
   "type": "timerTrigger",
   "direction": "in",
   "schedule": "0 * * * *"
   }
 ]
}

Adding LOGS:
Manual Run logs-
9/18/2024, 5:38:40.548 AM   "INFORMATION: Metrics response for 
adlsstrgacc12345: {
""cost"": 59,
""timespan"": ""2024-09-18T04:38:40Z/2024-09-18T05:38:40Z"",
""interval"": ""PT1H"",
""value"": [
{
  ""id"":""/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/UsedCapacity"",
  ""type"": ""Microsoft.Insights/metrics"",
  ""name"": {
    ""value"": ""UsedCapacity"",
    ""localizedValue"": ""Used capacity""
  },
 ""displayDescription"": ""The amount of storage used by the 
 storage account. For standard storage accounts, it's the sum of 
 capacity used by blob, table, file, and queue. For premium 
 storage accounts and Blob storage accounts, it is the same as 
 BlobCapacity or FileCapacity."",
  ""unit"": ""Bytes"",
  ""timeseries"": [
    {
      ""metadatavalues"": [],
      ""data"": [
        {
          ""timeStamp"": ""2024-09-18T04:38:00Z"",
          ""average"": 6128267
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  ""errorCode"": ""Success""
}
 ],
      ""namespace"": ""Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"",
      ""resourceregion"": ""northeurope""

Schedule run logs-
9/18/2024, 5:01:58.476 AM   "INFORMATION: Metrics response for 
adlsstrgacc12345: {
 ""cost"": 59,
 ""timespan"": ""2024-09-18T04:01:58Z/2024-09-18T05:01:58Z"",
 ""interval"": ""PT1H"",
 ""value"": [
  {
  ""id"": ""/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics/UsedCapacity"",
  ""type"": ""Microsoft.Insights/metrics"",
  ""name"": {
    ""value"": ""UsedCapacity"",
    ""localizedValue"": ""Used capacity""
    },
  ""displayDescription"": ""The amount of storage used by the storage account. For standard storage accounts, it's the sum of capacity used by blob, table, file, and queue. For premium storage accounts and Blob storage accounts, it is the same as BlobCapacity or FileCapacity."",
  ""unit"": ""Bytes"",
  ""timeseries"": [
    {
      ""metadatavalues"": [],
      ""data"": [
        {
          ""timeStamp"": ""2024-09-18T04:01:00Z""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  ""errorCode"": ""Success""
}
],
""namespace"": ""Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"",
""resourceregion"": ""northeurope""
}"  Information 1

requirements.psd
@{ # For latest supported version, go to 
'powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. # To use the Az module in 
 your function app, please uncomment the line below. 
'Az' = '12.*' }



Please also add your function.json to the question

added .json to question @SantiagoSquarzon

Noticed ""average"" metrics is missing in schedule run

@Nolan1513 How frequently, you want the function to trigger like once in a sec or once in a minute?

@Nolan1513 Is your issue resolved?

@IkhtesamAfrin The function supposed to run once every day but for testing purpose I'm running every hour. No, the issue is not resolved.

@Nolan1513 What is the issue? Is your function not getting executed as expected or getting any error?

@IkhtesamAfrin The code during schedule run does not fetch the size of storage account and fetches 0 value for all but during manual run the code runs perfectly displaying actual storage account size. Logs added above in question for schedule run and manual run

@Nolan1513 can you share your requirements file?

@IkhtesamAfrin added to question

@Nolan1513 I can see the value of average in the function app too.

I have used the same code in azure function app to get the storage account details and got expected response.
param($Timer)

# Get environment variables
$tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
$appId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPID')
$appName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPNAME')
$clientSecret = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_SECRET')

Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to call UC API"

# Connect to Azure with SPN
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $appId, $securePassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantId 
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
Write-Host "Subscriptions fetched: $($subscriptions.Count)"

# Define the tag key
$tagKey = "Business Data Domain"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$strg = @()
$current_date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    try {
        Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
        Write-Host "Set context to subscription: $($subscription.Name)"
        
        $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) }
        Write-Host "Storage accounts found in subscription $($subscription.Name): $($storageAccounts.Count)"
        
        if ($storageAccounts.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Host "No storage accounts with tag '$tagKey' found in subscription $($subscription.Name)."
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to set context for subscription: $($subscription.Name). Skipping."
        continue
    }
    
    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        Write-Host "Processing storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"

        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"
        
        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            Write-Host "Metrics response for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $($response.Content)"
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }
            
            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
                Write-Host "Average Capacity for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $averageCapacity"
            } else {
                Write-Host "Metric 'UsedCapacity' not found for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)."
                $averageCapacity = 0
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Error retrieving metrics for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $($_.Exception.Message)"
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }
          
        # Create a custom object for each storage account
        $objresults = [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName    = $subscription.Name
            StorageAccount      = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
            UsedCapacityInBytes = $averageCapacity
            TagName             = $tagKey
            TagValue            = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
        }
        # Add the object to the results array
        $strg += $objresults
    }

}

Write-Host "Checking if strg has data before exporting to CSV..."
if ($strg.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No data found in strg array!"
} else {
    Write-Host "strg array contains data. Proceeding to export..."
}

# Create folder to store source path
$localPath = "$(Get-Location)\strgacctmp"
If (-not (Test-Path -Path $localPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $localPath -ItemType 'Directory' -Force
    Write-Host "New Folder strgacctmp Created!"
} else {
    Write-Host "Folder already Exists!"
}


function uploadFileToBlob {
    param(
        [String] $LocalFilePath,
        [String] $TargetFileName
    )
    $tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
    $storage_account = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT')
    $subscription = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME')
    $filesystemName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME')
    $destPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_FOLDER_PATH_UC_DASHBOARD')

    Write-Host " ----Retrieved App Settings from Function App--- "
    Write-Host "ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT - $storage_account"
    Write-Host "ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME - $subscription"
    Write-Host "ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME - $filesystemName"
    Write-Host "Source - $LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "Destination Path - $destPath"
    Write-Host "Path from where files will be uploaded: $LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "-------------------------"


    Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to upload to ADLS"

    
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_account -UseConnectedAccount -ErrorAction Stop
    #$ctx

    try {
        $destPath += "/" + $TargetFileName
        New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $destPath -Source $LocalFilePath -ErrorAction Stop -Force
        Start-Sleep -seconds 2

        # Will execute on successful completion of folder upload
        Write-Host "File uploaded successfully!"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output " Error occured as below"
        $_
        exit
    }
}

# Export to CSV        
$CsvPath = $localPath + "\edpstrgaccsize$current_date.csv"
$strg | Export-Csv -Path $CsvPath -NoTypeInformation

#Upload to blob
$targetFileName = "edpstrgaccsize$($current_date).csv"
uploadFileToBlob -LocalFilePath $CsvPath -TargetFileName $targetFileName

Write-Host "Uploaded Storage Details-"

#Need to delete locally stored files in folder unitycatalogtmp
Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Filter *.csv | Remove-Item -Recurse

Write-Host "Script Completed"

This gives me expected response.

If you are not getting average capacity in the metrics response then you need to check the separate information logged for Average capacity of your storage account, it might be zero.
Code to fetch the Total capacity-
param($Timer)

# Get environment variables
$tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
$appId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPID')
$appName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_APPNAME')
$clientSecret = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ALPHA_SPN_SECRET')

Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to call UC API"

# Connect to Azure with SPN
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $clientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $appId, $securePassword
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantId 
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription
Write-Host "Subscriptions fetched: $($subscriptions.Count)"

# Define the tag key
$tagKey = "Business Data Domain"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$strg = @()
$current_date = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    try {
        Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
        Write-Host "Set context to subscription: $($subscription.Name)"
        
        $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) }
        Write-Host "Storage accounts found in subscription $($subscription.Name): $($storageAccounts.Count)"
        
        if ($storageAccounts.Count -eq 0) {
            Write-Host "No storage accounts with tag '$tagKey' found in subscription $($subscription.Name)."
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Warning "Failed to set context for subscription: $($subscription.Name). Skipping."
        continue
    }
    
    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        Write-Host "Processing storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"

        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Total"
        
        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            Write-Host "Metrics response for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $($response.Content)"
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }
            
            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $totalCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.total | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
                Write-Host "Total Capacity for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $totalCapacity"
            } else {
                Write-Host "Metric 'UsedCapacity' not found for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)."
                $totalCapacity = 0
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Error retrieving metrics for $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName): $($_.Exception.Message)"
            $totalCapacity = 0
        }
                
        # Create a custom object for each storage account
        $objresults = [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName    = $subscription.Name
            StorageAccount      = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
            UsedCapacityInBytes = $totalCapacity
            TagName             = $tagKey
            TagValue            = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
        }
        # Add the object to the results array
        $strg += $objresults
    }
}

Write-Host "Checking if strg has data before exporting to CSV..."
if ($strg.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host "No data found in strg array!"
} else {
    Write-Host "strg array contains data. Proceeding to export..."
}

# Create folder to store source path
$localPath = "$(Get-Location)\strgacctmp"
If (-not (Test-Path -Path $localPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $localPath -ItemType 'Directory' -Force
    Write-Host "New Folder strgacctmp Created!"
} else {
    Write-Host "Folder already Exists!"
}

function uploadFileToBlob {
    param(
        [String] $LocalFilePath,
        [String] $TargetFileName
    )
    $tenantId = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('UCAPI_TENANTID')
    $storage_account = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT')
    $subscription = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME')
    $filesystemName = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME')
    $destPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('ADLS_FOLDER_PATH_UC_DASHBOARD')

    Write-Host " ----Retrieved App Settings from Function App--- "
    Write-Host "ADLS_STORAGE_ACCOUNT - $storage_account"
    Write-Host "ADLS_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME - $subscription"
    Write-Host "ADLS_CONTAINER_NAME - $filesystemName"
    Write-Host "Source - $LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "Destination Path - $destPath"
    Write-Host "Path from where files will be uploaded: $LocalFilePath"
    Write-Host "-------------------------"

    Write-Host "Connecting Azure through $appName SPN login to upload to ADLS"
 
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storage_account -UseConnectedAccount -ErrorAction Stop
    #$ctx

    try {
        $destPath += "/" + $TargetFileName
        New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $destPath -Source $LocalFilePath -ErrorAction Stop -Force
        Start-Sleep -seconds 2

        # Will execute on successful completion of folder upload
        Write-Host "File uploaded successfully!"
    }
    catch {
        Write-Output " Error occured as below"
        $_
        exit
    }
}

# Export to CSV        
$CsvPath = $localPath + "\edpstrgaccsize$current_date.csv"
$strg | Export-Csv -Path $CsvPath -NoTypeInformation

#Upload to blob
$targetFileName = "edpstrgaccsize$($current_date).csv"
uploadFileToBlob -LocalFilePath $CsvPath -TargetFileName $targetFileName

Write-Host "Uploaded Storage Details-"

#Need to delete locally stored files in folder unitycatalogtmp
Get-ChildItem -Path $localPath -Filter *.csv | Remove-Item -Recurse

Write-Host "Script Completed"


Where do I check this separate information logged for Average capacity, Do you mean in the metrics ! Also, like I said if I manually trigger the function it will give the actual storage account size but only fails when the function runs during schedule time trigger run.

@Nolan1513 The screenshot I have shared is from the scheduled timer trigger function only. You should see all the logged information in the invocation section of function

I have updated log image above, The captured average capacity is 0 in schedule run.

@Nolan1513 Try to change it to Total instead of Average in https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Total. Average capacity might be zero sometimes depends on the timespan when you are querying it due to no activity at that time. So UsedCapacity reflects 0. So you can use Total, it will give you data every time in all the scheduled run

@Nolan1513 Added code for total capacity, please check

@Nolan1513 Did you try to use Total?

Apologies, I just noticed your old comment. Added the new API call with aggregation=Total. will let you know the results in an hour as it has to run as per schedule.

I have modified the API aggregation=total and the value for is zero for all storage accounts. Also we opened a Microsoft case and they noticed the same behaviour in schedule run. looks like MS back end issue. will post more updates.

Did you use my modified script? Actually I am getting expected response when using Total

I used your script and it gives me the storage account sizes but still I noticed five of them  fetching zero value. Microsoft is currently investigating this issue, looks like internal MS issue. I will keep posting more details here.

Issue is with the API call and Microsoft has no resolution yet.
